# Finding a centroid of areas bounded by some curves

Tags: calculus

I was familiarizing the concepts related to the centroid of areas bounded by some curves and I happened to come across this problem while studying. It goes like this:

"Find the centroid of the area bounded by the curves $\sqrt x + \sqrt y = \sqrt a, x = 0$ and $y = 0.$"

I end up scratching my head to the question above. I'm more comfortable at graphing, but it seems I can't do it due to the $a$ on the equation. How do you answer it?

Comment: plot it for a few different values of $a$, and try to intuit how the curve evolves with a change to $a$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method is by area computation and averaging for C.G.by taking moment of area.

$$ \sqrt x + \sqrt y  =\sqrt a $$

$$ y= a + x -2 \sqrt{ax }$$

Leaving out a couple of steps as an exercise

$$ \int y\, dx = ax + x^2/2 -2 \sqrt {a }\cdot a ^{3/2} \cdot \frac23 $$

$$ \int_0^a dA = a^2( \frac{3}{2}-\frac{4}{3}) = \frac{a^2}{6} $$

$$ \int y^2 dx = \int_0^a( a^2 + x^2 + 4 a x + 2 a x -4 \sqrt {a} x ^{3/2} -4  a^{3/2}\sqrt{ x}  $$

$$ = a^3\left( 1 +\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3}{1}-\frac{8}{5}-\frac{8}{3}  \right) =\frac{a^3}{15} $$

By application of Pappu's area theorem  we can find center of gravity for revolved area (now corrected).

$$ Vol =\int y^2 dx = ( 2 \pi \bar y Area ) =  2 \pi \bar y \int y dx $$

or

$$ \bar y = \frac{\int y^2 dx}{2\int \,y dx}=\frac{6a}{2 \times 15}=\frac{a}{5}= \bar x, $$

since there is symmetry about $x=y, \bar x=\bar y$.

Else you can also directly find $\bar x$ using  $$  \frac{\int x\,y\, dx}{2\int \,y dx} $$

in the same way.And as an exercise I recommend finding areas, volumes, centers of gravity for each of the three areas comprising total revolved area $a^2$.

[image: CG of axes tangented Parabola]

Comment: In my book, the centroid of area described by the problem above is $\left ( \frac{a}{5}, \frac{a}{5} \right ).$ Almost there!XD

Comment: Now got it OK in full..

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be approached by starting with the formal definition of the centroid of an area, namely,

$$\mathbf{R}=\frac{\iint\mathbf{r}dydx}{\iint dydx},\quad \mathbf{r}=\mathbf{\hat i}x+\mathbf{\hat j}y$$

where the denominator is seen to be the area.

In the present case we have
$$y=(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x})^2=a\left(1-\sqrt{x/a}\right)^2\quad x,y\in[0,a]$$

Let's begin with the area as this will demonstrate the integral methods to be used.

$$A=\int_0^a\int_0^{(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x})^2} dydx=\int_0^a(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x})^2dx=2a^2\int_0^1 t(1-t)^2dt$$

where $t=\sqrt{x/a}$ and $dx=2at\ dt$. The integral is the well-known beta function,

$$B(\nu,\mu)=\int_0^1 t^{\nu-1}(1-t)^{\mu-1}dt=\frac{\Gamma(\nu)\Gamma(\mu)}{\Gamma(\nu+\mu)}, \quad \nu,\mu>0$$

So that

$$A=2a^2\frac{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(3)}{\Gamma(5)}=\frac{a^2}{6}$$

Now consider the $x$-component of the centroid. Making the same transformation, we find that

$$R_xA=2a^3\int_0^1 t^3(1-t)^2 dt=2a^3B(4,3)=2a^3\frac{\Gamma(4)\Gamma(3)}{\Gamma(7)}=\frac{a^3}{30}\\
R_x=\frac{a}{5}
$$

Similarly, for the $y$-component,

$$R_yA=a^2\int_0^1 t(1-t)^4 dt=a^3B(2,5)=a^3\frac{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(5)}{\Gamma(7)}=\frac{a^3}{30}\\
R_y=\frac{a}{5}$$

It's not surprising that $R_x=R_y$ due to the symmetry of the curve about the line $x=y$. These results have been verified numerically.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=1$ the shape $T$ in question can  be parametrized  by
$$\psi:\quad \{(u,v)\>|\> u\geq0,\  v\geq0,\  u+v\leq1\}=:S \to T,\qquad (u,v)\mapsto (x,y):=(u^2,v^2)\ .$$ The  Jacobian of $\psi$ is $4uv$. The first coordinate  of the centroid $(\xi,\eta)$ of $T$ is then given by
$$\xi={\int_S u^2\cdot 4uv\ {\rm d}(u,v)\over\int_S4uv\>{\rm d}(u,v)}={\int_0^1\int_0^{1-u}u^2\cdot 4uv\ dv\>du\over\int_0^1\int_0^{1-u}4uv\>dv\>du}={1/30\over 1/6}={1\over5}\ .$$
For arbitrary $a>0$ we therefore obtain $$(\xi,\eta)=\left({a\over5},{a\over5}\right)\ .$$